# On-tap function not working inside template tag

Tags: html, data-binding, polymer, web-component

I am very new to polymer and data-binding. I am facing this issue and couldn't find something substantial to help me. Following is my code snippet:

```
<sortable-table>
  <sortable-column cellTemplate="callTemplate">Call</sortable-column>
  <template id="callTemplate">
    <td class="customClass">
      <core-icon-button icon="create" on-tap="{{functionCall}}"></core-icon-button>
    </td>
  </template>
</sortable-table>

<script>
  Polymer('element-name', {
    functionCall: function() {
      alert("hi");
    }
  });
</script>
```

But I am unable to run it. Please advise on what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Sortable table is a complicated web-component, [provided by Steven Skelton](https://github.com/stevenrskelton/sortable-table). There is no way one could play with it without strong understanding of fundamental webcomponents and polymer’s polyfill concepts.

I would recommend you to start with reading docs at [Polymer project website](https://www.polymer-project.org/).

To use `sortable-table` you’ll need to create polymer project, `bower install sortable-table`, import polyfills etc. It won’t run from local static `html` page.

Further reading would be the home page of component at github (linked in the beginning of this comment.)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing a " } "

```
Polymer('element-name', {
        functionCall: function() {
                alert("hi");
        }
});
```